# getElementById doesn't return the hidden field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Ours is struts 1.4 based application and we are using `jQuery` Mobile.

When there is a Business Exception, we re-display the page with exception message.

However, I have set a hidden variable that I will use to determine which radio buttons and text field to display.

However, when I try to access this hidden variable, I always get undefined.

When I see page --> view --> source. I could see the hidden variable and its value.

I tried a simple code:

`document.getElementByID('test');`

Doesn't return anything.

Did anyone faced the similar problem? Please help.

Comment: Please post your markup and code.

Comment: This will return the element. So to get the value of this element you have to write alert(document.getElementById("test").value); Try this, it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery code like

```
var myVar = $('#test').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `document.getElementById('test')` (note the lower case D)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, use jQuery. And wrap it in document.ready so it's not running before the DOM element exists.

```
$(function() { // shorthand for document.ready
    // get the value of the element, not the element's object
    var myHiddenVar = $('#test').val(); 

    // spit it out
    alert(myHiddenVar); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your replies. Sorry for the typo. Yes. I meant lowercase 'd' in document.getElementById('test').

I found the problem. As I am using Jquery mobile, I needed to disable AJAX on form submission. I just added the below script after the jquery core and before jquery mobile and it worked like a champ. I used firebug and noted that there are two 'div' tags that are created when the page is reloaded with error message from backend. One hidden field in one of the div's has a value and one hidden field in the other div doesn't have a value but both have the same id. After disable AJAX there was only div tag and only one Id element and hence it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
{
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
      ajaxEnabled: false
  });
});
</script>
```